# Cannot install Microsoft Office 64-bit after removing Office 32-bit

Tags: microsoft-office, 64-bit, uninstall, 32-bit

I have been working with Microsoft Office 365 32-bit installation on my laptop with Windows 10 Pro 64-bit for a long time, and now need to replace it with the 64-bit edition. However, I can't do this. I removed the 32-bit Office using its native installer or even with the Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant according to the article [Uninstall Office from a PC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8), but this didn't help. When I launch the downloaded online 64-bit Office installer (OfficeSetup.exe), it always throws this screen:

[image: Couldn't Install Office]

Obviously, there are remnants of the 32-bit Office installation in the registry or on the hard drive that prevents me from installing the 64-bit version. Does anybody know how to find and remove them manually? Or is there another automated way to get rid of the previous 32-bit Office installation to install the 64-bit version instead?

Comment: Did you reboot the PC before attempting to install the 64-bit version?

Comment: I can find a bit on other people having this issue but (like you), I can''t see a fix.  [this person](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2104160-blank-program-list-office-64-bit-install-error) solved it with a "keep everything" reinstall.  This implies to me that it is a windows problem but who knows?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve this problem myself. The following article in Russian helped me with that:

https://winitpro.ru/index.php/2017/12/11/office-all-versions-removal-scripts/

Actually it refers the scripts from the following GitHub repository:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-IT-Pro-Deployment-Scripts/tree/master/Office-ProPlus-Deployment/Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls

I launched the vbs scripts from the command prompt with admin rights. Here is an example how to remove the remnants of Office 365 Click-to-Run on a pc with 64-bit Windows:

```
%SystemRoot%\SysWow64\cscript.exe OffScrubC2R.vbs ALL /NoCancel /Force /OSE
```

This combination of switches for the script allows you to see what the script does because every step is logged on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to uninstall Office manually?

Please refer to the steps of "Manually remove a Click-to-Run installation of Office" in the articel "[Manually uninstall Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manually-uninstall-office-4e2904ea-25c8-4544-99ee-17696bb3027b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)".

If it does not work, I suggest you install 32-bit Office first, then uninstall it again for a test.

Comment: I removed all remnants of Office I could find according to that article (both Click-to-Run and MSI installations), but this didn't help. Installing the 32-bit Office and uninstalling it with tis native uninstaller (with reboot) also didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

On a computer with multiple users, is it possible for one user to have one user with 32-bit office and another with 64-bit?

To uninstall 32-bit and install 64-bit for me, do I have to uninstall office for every user and then install 64-bit for every user?

Comment: This should be a new question. It does not meet this site's definition of an Answer.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem when installing Office 2021 Professional Plus with a key. The trick is to uninstall all 32bit Office components first with the normal deinstallation procedure, including MS project, language packages or old outlook version. Go through your installed Apps and search for Office and Microsoft (don’t deinstall all ) The installation of Office 2021 Professional Plus with 64bit works after removing all old Office 32bit components.